# Preventing users from deleting Google Calendar events

Tags: calendar

After switching over our email from self-hosting to GMail, my Sr. SysAdmin is looking for us to consolidate our company calendars into one singular Google Calendar.

With our current system, if a user marks a vacation day, only the Office Manager is able to go back and edit the entry after that date (to prevent people from giving themselves free vacation days).

As far as I can tell, with Google Calendar, if the calendar is shared company-wide, any user can create, edit, and/or delete an event.  Is there a setting somewhere to restrict access to completed events?

Comment: What did Google Support say about this? Give 'em a call - they're very good.

Comment: Have you tried this?, > [Google Calendar Help Fourm](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/MvifxjuQqBw)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not possible restrict permission to add/modify. Currently is possible to choose these permissions:

- Change and share
- Change
- View details
- View availability

To protect your data when someone deletes an event, you can track changes with the Notifications: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?rd=1

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad system because anyone can delete your events.  There should be a way to share an event but only allow it to be deleted by the person who put the event in.